# Linq: The "opposite" of Take?

Tags: c#, linq

Using Linq; how can I do the "opposite" of Take?

I.e. instead of getting the first n elements such as in

```
aCollection.Take(n)
```

I want to get everything but the last n elements. Something like

```
aCollection.Leave(n)
```

(Don't ask why :-)

Edit

I suppose I can do it this way `aCollection.TakeWhile((x, index) => index < aCollection.Count - n)` Or in the form of an extension

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Leave<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int n) 
{ 
  return source.TakeWhile((x, index) => index < source.Count() - n); 
}
```

But in the case of *Linq to SQL* or *NHibernate Linq* it would have been nice if the generated SQL took care of it and generated something like (for SQL Server/T-SQL)

`SELECT TOP(SELECT COUNT(*) -@n FROM ATable) * FROM ATable` Or some other more clever SQL implementation.

I suppose there is nothing like it?
(But the edit was actually not part of the question.)

Comment: Note: This is not the same as Skip!

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast!
Looks like Shedal's and Jim Dagg's answer is the best for my purpose.
How do I know which of these to select as correct answer? Jim was quicker, but Shedal got the votes.

Comment: Accept Shedal's answer. Reverse won't work on database, as database inherently need a qualifier on which field you wanted to sort, it has a runtime error when I tested on ORM. I tested Shedal's code on ORM, his code runs fine

Comment: Actually, Shedal is quicker, as of this writing, he answered 29 minutes ago; Jim Dagg's was 27 minutes ago

Comment: @MichaelBuen: You're correct, Shedal was first. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I keep thinking that it's odd that I didn't see the solution (as in the accepted answer) immediately myself since it is basically the same as the SQL that I started from. @:-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
aCollection.Take(aCollection.Count() - n);
```

**EDIT:** Just as a piece of interesting information which came up in the comments - you may think that the `IEnumerable`'s extension method `.Count()` is slow, because it would iterate through all elements. But in case the actual object implements `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`, it will just use the `.Count` property which should be O(1). So performance will not suffer in that case.

You can see the source code of `IEnumerable.Count()` [at TypeDescriptor.net](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/367291-System.Linq.Enumerable.Count%5BTSource%5D%28IEnumerable%601%29).

Comment: Do you mean `aCollection.Count()`? `Length` is a property of arrays.

Comment: that take at the end is not needed as well

Comment: more efficient than the double reverse as well

Comment: +1, nice one. BTW, I don't think the final `Take(n)` is necessary.

Comment: And of course, the assumption is that `n < aCollection.Count()`

Comment: An important item to note: If we can strengthen the requirement so that `aCollection` is an `IList` instead of an `IEnumerable`, then this can get faster. Depends heavily on the application though.

Comment: @Stargazer712 Actually, I think that the IEnumerable's `Count()` extension method checks if the instance `is IList<T>`, and if it is, calls its `Count` property.

Comment: +1.  It's worth mentioning that (unless `aCollection` is of a type that implements `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`) this requires iterating once completely to get the count, before the second partial iteration.  Given the requirement, there's no way around that, however.

Comment: @Shedal that's almost correct.  `Count` is a property of `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>`, so `Count()` checks for those interfaces before using the iterate-and-count approach.

Comment: @phoog I believe it could be avoid by buffering `n` elements but I am not sure it is worth it?

Comment: @NetMage whether it's worth it depends on how much you know about the object implementing the interface.

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty sure there's no built-in method for this, but this can be done easily by chaining `Reverse` and `Skip`:

```
aCollection.Reverse().Skip(n).Reverse()
```

Comment: I think this is better: `aCollection.Skip(aCollection.Count() - n)`, assuming `n < aCollection.Count()`.

Comment: Avoiding 2 calls to Reverse() in favor of 1 call to Count() is definitely the way to go

Comment: @Oded: I agree, and I already upvoted Shedal's answer. I'll keep mine here anyway as an alternative solution.

Comment: @Heinzi, oh definitely keep it up. Just because it isn't the fastest solution doesn't mean that it is not a solution :)

Comment: @Stargazer712: Probably. Since LINQ makes no performance guarantees on either Reverse or Count, it will depend on the actual collection type -- if the collection is a doubly-linked list with a direction flag, Reverse could be a O(1) operation. But I also think that Count will be faster *in the general case*.

Comment: Hmm. This still produces the skip result but reversed. Also Reverse is a List<> method and not for IEnumerable<>, right?

Comment: @UlfÅkerstedt: It's for IEnumerable<>, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx. Why do you think it would produce the wrong result? `.Reverse.Skip(n)` removes the *last* n elements, and the final Reverse restores the original order.

Comment: @Heinzi: Sorry I missed the double reverse. Read it as aCollection.Skip(n).Reverse()... My bad.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there's a built-in function for this.

`aCollection.Take(aCollection.Count - n)`

should be suitable; taking the total number of items in the collection minus n should skip the last n elements.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping with the `IEnumerable` philosphy, and going through the enumeration once for cases where `ICollection` isn't implemented, you can use these extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this ICollection<T> src, int drop) => src.Take(src.Count - drop);

public static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int drop) {
    IEnumerable<T> IEnumHelper() {
        using (var esrc = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            var buf = new Queue<T>();
            while (drop-- > 0)
                if (esrc.MoveNext())
                    buf.Enqueue(esrc.Current);
                else
                    break;

            while (esrc.MoveNext()) {
                buf.Enqueue(esrc.Current);
                yield return buf.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }

    return (src is ICollection<T> csrc) ? csrc.Leave(drop) : IEnumHelper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be much more efficient than the solutions with a double-reverse, since it creates only one list and only enumerates the list once.

```
public static class Extensions
{
   static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int numToSkip)
   {
      var list = items.ToList();
      // Assert numToSkip <= list count.
      list.RemoveRange(list.Count - numToSkip, numToSkip);
      return List
   }
}


string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var chars = alphabet.Leave(10); // abcdefghijklmnop
```

Answer (score -2):

Currently, C# has a `TakeLast(n)` method defined which takes characters from the end of the string.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212114(v=vs.103).aspx